# Lua odd table behaviour

Tags: list, indexing, lua

In my code, I set a variable to the contents of a table, like so:

```
colorTable = {{255, 255, 255}}
color = colorTable[1]
```

My problem is when I edit the value of `color` it changes the original value in `colorTable`

So in the beginning, `colorTable[1][1]` equals `255`, but after I run this:

```
color[1] = color[1] - 10
```

`colorTable[1][1]` equals `245`.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not an odd behaviour, its the behaviour one would expect if one would have at least read the "Basic Concepts" chapter of the Lua manual.
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1  It's like the second page...
Tables are always copied by reference. color refers to the very same table as colorTable[1], hence colour[1] refers to colourTable[1][1].

Comment: To be clear, `color[1] = color[1] - 10` does not "edit the value of `color`"; it just updates the value of its member with the key number 1. `color` is not changed at all; it is the same table reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following line *creates* a reference (`color`) to the table within `colorTable`:

```
color = colorTable[1]
```

We are only manipulating the reference to the value, which does not suggest any means of copy.

If we, instead, try the following:

```
color = {table.unpack(colorTable[1])}
```

We are calling the constructor, filling it with values *unpacked* from `colorTable[1]`, which contains `255, 255, 255`. We then have a *new* table holding these values and performing arithmetic on them does not affect the ones in `colorTable`:

```
print(colorTable[1][1])
```

Result:

```
255
```

subsequently:

```
color[1] = color[1] - 10

print(colorTable[1][1])
```

Result:

```
255
```